# How to load Different adapters on same listview on Button Click-[Android]?

Tags: button, android-listview, onclick, adapter, baseadapter

My requirement is to load different adapters on same listview using buttons to switch between adapters.

I've tried this

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

ImageButton fo,fl,ci,ani;
ListView l;
String flo[],foo[],cit[],an[];
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  String flo[] = {"Rose","Lily","SunFlower","Lotus","Tulips"};
    String foo[] = {"Maggie","Manchurian","Pizza","Burger","French Fries"};
    String cit[] = {"New York","Los Angeles","Las Vegas","Texas","Manhattan"};
    String an[] = {"Lion","Tiger","Penguins","Panda","Elephant"};

    fo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);
    fl = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
    ci = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);
    ani = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton4);
    l =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView);


    fo.setOnClickListener(this);
    fl.setOnClickListener(this);
    ci.setOnClickListener(this);
    ani.setOnClickListener(this);



}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId()==R.id.imageButton2)
    {
        food f = new food(this,foo);
        l.setAdapter(f);
    }

}
```

}

And I'm getting the following Error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.nike.assignmentadapter, PID: 2565
>       java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
>               at com.example.nike.assignmentadapter.food.getCount(food.java:41)
>               at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:487)
>               at com.example.nike.assignmentadapter.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:74)
>               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4756)
>               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19749)
>               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)

Food class

```
public class food extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

String s[];
Context c;
Button li;
Button sh ;
int a[] = {R.drawable.fl1,R.drawable.fl2,R.drawable.fl3,R.drawable.fl4,R.drawable.fl5};

public food(Context context, String[] xperia) {

    s = xperia;
    c = context;

}



@Override
public int getCount() {
    return s.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return s.length;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater ln = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = ln.inflate(R.layout.food, null);
    TextView t= (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    ImageView i = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    li = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.like4);
     sh = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.share4);



    String s1=s[position];
    t.setText(s1);
    i.setImageResource(a[position]);

    li.setOnClickListener(this);
    sh.setOnClickListener(this);




    return v;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(v.getId()==R.id.like4)
    {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("Thanks Note");
        builder.setMessage("Thank you for Liking ");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.foo_t);
        builder.setPositiveButton("To Share", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                Uri webpage = Uri.parse("http://www.sonymobile.com");
                Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
                c.startActivity(webIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.show();

               }
    else
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder= new AlertDialog.Builder(c);
        builder.setTitle("Thanks Note");
        builder.setMessage("Thank you for Sharing on Your Facebook");
        builder.setIcon(R.drawable.foo_t);
        builder.setPositiveButton("To Facebook", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                // User clicked OK button
                Uri webpage = Uri.parse("https://www.facebook.com");
                Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, webpage);
                c.startActivity(webIntent);
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {


    ImageButton fo,fl,ci,ani;
    ListView l;

    String flo[],foo[],cit[],an[];  
    // these are your global variables available to access 
    // in any part of the coding.  Currently they have no 
    // data assigned to them in other words they are null

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // here we have assigned data to the global variables declared
        // outside of the OnCreate function and available to the onClick 
        // call.
        // Using String flo[] = {John, Doe} means you are creating
        // new local versions of the String arrays that are not available
        // globally. Instead of assigning the data to the variables
        // available globally, and to the onClick call, the data is given  
        // to the local variables only accessible in the OnCreate function 
        // function and available until OnCreate finishes.

        flo = new String[]{"Rose","Lily","SunFlower","Lotus","Tulips"};
        foo = new String[]{"Maggie","Manchurian","Pizza","Burger","French Fries"};
        cit = new String[]{"New York","Los Angeles","Las Vegas","Texas","Manhattan"};
        an = new String[]{"Lion","Tiger","Penguins","Panda","Elephant"};

        fo = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
        l =(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


        fo.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        if (v.getId()==R.id.imageButton1)
        {
            System.out.println("foo: " + foo);
            food f = new food(this,foo);
            l.setAdapter(f);
        }

    }
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

}

Comment: food.java class posted

Comment: Ultimately I think the string array in the food class isn't being populated properly.

Comment: The adapter is Working Properly.Only problem is it not being called when I try to call it using button. If i define 

food f = new food(this,foo);
        l.setAdapter(f);

in OnCreate the code works

But my requirement is to load the adapter on button click so while adding the above shown lines under OnClick it gives error , what i've already added

Comment: Going on the error output it crashes when it calls getcount because the array is null. So at some point string array s is losing its data. Hopefully someone with more experience can have a l look v soon

Comment: It would be the same error but you should have some extra lines that post the values of xperia and s.

Comment: Solution please I m dying hehehe... but seriously I need help

Comment: sorry about the delay it seems foo is never ever populated ive loaded your code in my eclipse and done some outputs null data in foo, xperia and in s. currently looking at fixing it.bear with me

Comment: fixed it was obvious when I found it.

check answer

Comment: Still no luck dude. I m making it on Studio. But could that cause a problem.??

Comment: Whaaaaat? I ran the app and got the adapter to change by clicking the button. Studio shouldn't make a difference. Is it the same error or a different one?

Comment: You sure you've changed the right code? Post the updated code in place of what's you've already got on here

Comment: I exactly what you said.... If it worked for you. Can you please post the whole code

Comment: full code added on now. I thing i forgot the take the [] out of the foo[] = new String[] part

Comment: Thanx dude it worked. Thank u sooo soooo soooooo much... One more thing.. Plzz teach me what i did wrong. An thank u soo much.

Comment: Comments added to the coding.  Basically you had your global String arrays declared outside of OnCreate and then you had local String arrays with the same name declared and assigned data inside the OnCreate.  So the data never gets assigned to the global variables only the local ones which OnClick cannot access